Is English Unique in having so Many Animal Words?
In English, it is common for a multiple words to refer to animals of the same taxon differently depending on sex, age, or other factors. For example:
Taxon: Horse
Reproductive Adult Male: Stallion
Castrated Adult Male: Gelding
Adult Female: Mare
Young: Foal
Male Young: Colt
Female Young: Filly
Collective: Herd
Wikipedia has a pretty exhaustive list. Notice how these words have different roots. I was wondering how unique this feature is to English.
While trying to research this I kept finding article about how the name for a taxon translates to different languages, which isn't what I am looking for. For example, this site says that 'horse' translates to 'סוּס' in Hebrew, but doesn't mention how that is only for a male horse and the female horse is actually 'סוּסָה'. Notice how these two words share a root, unlike in English. I did manage to find a post on this site saying collective nouns for animals are unique to English because they are based on an English hunting tradition, which is backed by other sources [1, 2, 3].
I can understand why these different terms exist. The sentence, "Go to the market and get me a gelding," is much shorter than, "Go to the market and get me an adult, castrated, male horse." What interests me is how the roots are so different.

Horses aren't native to Israel and סוס might be a loan word; for sheep and cows Hebrew has as many terms as English has for horse, or more

I am fairly certain that a society will naturally develop more words to describe animals that are economically important in order to facilitate trade. The Wikipedia list of English animal names reflects this. Newts, snails, and crows are all native to Britain but lack as many names as horses, chickens, or geese. That is not what my question is about. My question focuses on the etymology of the words, which are so varied despite referring to related creatures.

This is not too unique to English.  You can see the etymologies on Wiktionary, all of these words have cognates in mainland continental Europe.  What is relatively unique to English is the specific collectives for different types of animals.

@AdamBittlingmayer tbf many of the specific collectives were invented largely as a meme in the 18th and 19th centuries (on the basis of some more limited and rather less eccentric variation already introduced in the jargon of noble hunters in the middle ages), and whilst often acknowledged as "correct", most rarely see actual use

@Tristan Yep, not ancient and not frequent, and to the degree that it does exist, based on the history of English and Hebrew, it makes sense that some registers of English had this and modern Hebrew does not.  German also has a distinct hunters' argot, and like Hebrew/Aramaic some of it worked itself into the mainstream vernacular or even standard written language, but in my life across NY, SF, Zurich and Berlin and places with no local German at all, I don't see many young marmots or steel wire traps, let alone learn specific German hunters' words for them.
